# Analyzing RC circuit that has two "switch"

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: The question]

I need to find Vc(t) between 0<=t<=0.01 secs , but teacher draws the second switch as opened. We want to find Vc(t) when t is "less or equal" to 0.01, then why we dont take the switch as closed? Because it is closed at t=0.01 sec. 
Is it because of its limit from the left? Because vc(t-) is not equal vc(t+).

And another thing that makes me confused, when v goes infinite, teacher takes this circuit to find v infinite.(I am talking about the first part of the question. 1-Find vc(t) when 0<=t<=0.01 secs)

[image: Infinite circuit]

But after long time (after 0.01 secs), the second switch must be closed. Because infinity is greater then 0.01 sec. Then why we take that switch as opened?

Thanks!

Comment: This is just an academic exercise, so 'why don't we take the switch as closed', etc..., is irrelevant. Do what the question tells you; don't make up your own questions.

Comment: @Chu i think you misunderstood me. I didnt understand the solution. I asked like that because i want to learn the reason why we open that switch or not. It is closed at t=10ms but to find v infinity, we open it. Why?

Comment: You can find a \$\small V_{\infty}\$ for any combination of switch settings. You are misinterpreting the question in this respect.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, for \$t<0\$ we know that the circuit is equivalent to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTWqyc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage that is created across the capacitor for \$t<0\$, given by:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right):=\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_1}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\left(\text{R}_3\left.\right\vert\left.\right\vert\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\cdot\frac{\text{I}_x}{\text{s}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=$$
$$\lim_{\text{s}\to0}\text{s}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_1}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\left(\text{R}_3\left.\right\vert\left.\right\vert\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}\cdot\frac{\text{I}_x}{\text{s}}=\frac{\text{I}_x\text{R}_1\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\tag1$$

Where I used the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) and \$\$ means the [parallel resistor equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Series_and_parallel_circuits).

Now, for \$0\le t<\tau\$ we have the following equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcmXDY.png)</sup>

Using the [discharge equation of the capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#DC_circuits) we get (you can also show that using KVL and KCL), we know that:

- $$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{CR}_3}\right)\tag2$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\frac{\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)}{\text{R}_3}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{CR}_3}\right)\tag3$$

So, for \$0\le t<\tau\$ we get that the total power in the resistor \$\text{R}_3\$ is given by:

$$\text{P}_{0\le t<\tau\text{|}\text{R}_3}=\text{R}_3\left(\frac{\text{I}_x\text{R}_1}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\right)^2\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{2\tau}{\text{CR}_3}\right)\tag4$$

So, for the part when \$t\ge\tau\$, we get the same voltage equation as above. But with a different starting voltage and different resistive value:

$$\text{V}_{t\ge\tau\text{|}\text{C}}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_{0\le t<\tau\text{|}\text{C}}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\text{C}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\right)\tag5$$

So, the total power is equal to:

- For \$\text{R}_3\$:
  $$\text{P}_{\text{total}\text{|}\text{R}_3}=\text{P}_{0\le t<\tau\text{|}\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_{t\ge\tau\text{|}\text{C}}^2\left(t\right)}{\text{R}_3}\tag6$$
- For \$\text{R}_4\$:
  $$\text{P}_{\text{total}\text{|}\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_{t\ge\tau\text{|}\text{C}}^2\left(t\right)}{\text{R}_4}\tag7$$

> Using your values I got:
>
> - For \$\text{R}_3\$:
>   $$\text{P}_{\text{total}\text{|}\text{R}_3}=\frac{32}{125\exp\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)}+\frac{32}{125}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{4}{5}-100t\right)\tag6$$
> - For \$\text{R}_4\$:
>   $$\text{P}_{\text{total}\text{|}\text{R}_4}=\frac{8}{125}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{4}{5}-100t\right)\tag7$$